# Ruby grep all lines inside <body> tag

Tags: ruby

How to grep all lines within the `body` tag using `ruby`? I know this can be solved with `Nokogiri` but I want to learn how to do it.

Example:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

From the above example, I want all the lines within the `body` tag, which is `h1`, `div`, and `button` element.

File path link: `"#{Rails.root}/app/templates/example.html"`

Comment: <button> is also within <body>. Are you looking for closest child elements only?

Comment: What does _"all the lines"_ mean? Do you want a multi-line string or the Nokogiri nodes or something else? Please be more specific.

Comment: I want multi-line strings.

Comment: @JDelorean all the elements inside `body` tag.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions unless you *really* know what you're doing and all the ways it can go wrong. In any non-trivial case, you need to *parse* HTML for your results to be reliable.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Are there any vulnerabilities? Because the file is from my own computer.

Comment: @AbeidAhmed It's not just about untrusted data; it's about [irregular data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1301972). Unless it's part of a text fixture, you can pretty much count on regex solutions for HTML parsing to fail eventually, except in the most trivial of use cases. YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description isn't precise enough to understand exactly what you want.

```rb
str = <<~STR
<body>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</body>
STR

str[%r{<body>(.*)</body>}m, 1]
```

kind of does what you describe, but it won't be reliable in all cases. It will begin and end capture between any `<body>` and `</body>`, respectively, even if those characters are found in HTML comments. An example that would fail:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</body>
<!-- </body> -->
```

Comment: The `html` is inside a file and when I try to read the file like `File.read(path)[%r{<body>(.*)</body>}m, 1]`, it is returning `nil`.

Comment: It is working, there was a `class` attr in `body` tag. Thanks!

Comment: While not bulletproof, you can anchor the body tags so that they won't pick up stray comments from the fragment, e.g. `str[%r{^<body>\n(.*)\n</body>}m, 1]`. However, as whitespace can vary without changing the semantics of the fragment, it still can't be as reliable as an actual parse.

Answer (score 2):

### Use XPath

You can collect the nodes within your body tag using XPath as follows:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html_fragment = <<~'EOF'
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </body>
EOF

fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.parse html_fragment
nodes    = fragment.xpath './/body/*'
```

After that, you can do whatever you like with the nodes to address your specific use case. Some examples include:

```
nodes.map &:text
#=> ["Hello world", "\nSubmit\n"]

nodes.map &:to_s
#=> ["<h1>Hello world</h1>", "<div>\n<button>Submit</button>\n</div>"]

nodes.to_html
#=> "<h1>Hello world</h1><div>\n<button>Submit</button>\n</div>"

nodes.inner_html
#=> "Hello world\n<button>Submit</button>\n"
```

### See Also

- [Parsing an HTML / XML Document](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#parsing-an-html-xml-document)
- [Searching an HTML / XML Document](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)
- [Nokogiri::Searchable#xpath](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#xpath-instance_method)
- [Nokogiri Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet)